# absolute value calculation not working...?

Tags: java

I have been debugging this problem for over an hour now and have no idea what is wrong. I am attempting to simply compare two integers and store the smaller one to the `tempDistance` variable.

However, this continues to fail every time. I have no idea why.

Observe:

```
public void park() {

    StreetName temp = null;

    int tempDistance = 10000;

    for(StreetName street : streets) {

        int yLocale = this.y - street.getY();
        int xLocale = this.x - street.getX();
        int num = yLocale + xLocale;

        System.out.println(Math.abs(num) + " absolute value");

        if(Math.abs(num) < tempDistance) {

            tempDistance = num;
            temp = street;
        }


    }
    System.out.println("Parked at " + temp.getName());
```

`street` values are as follows:

```
streets.add(new StreetName("Ames Street", 0, 0));
streets.add(new StreetName("Nevada Street", 40, 0));
streets.add(new StreetName("Roland Street", 15, -30));
streets.add(new StreetName("Jordan Street", -15, -5));
streets.add(new StreetName("Granger Steet", -22, 20));
streets.add(new StreetName("Baxter Street", 75, 19));
streets.add(new StreetName("MinBurn Street", -35, 55));
```

When I enter "15 west, 5 south", Jordan street should be selected. Instead, Ames street is continually selected.

Here is the console output:

[image]

Does anyone understand what is going on here?

Comment: Probably `tempDistance` is most negative for Ames street. Try `tempDistance = Math.abs(num);`

Comment: What tobias_k said, and also don't you want `Math.abs` on `xLocale` and `yLocale` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that for Ames Street, `num` is negative, and thus `tempDistance` gets negative, and thus none of the later checks apply, as no `abs` number can be smaller than a negative number.

You should probably do `tempDistance = Math.abs(num);`

However, this may still be wrong, as `xLocale` and `yLocale` might "cancel" each other out if both are large and one is positive and one negative. Thus, you should take the `abs` at this point already:

```
int num = Math.abs(yLocale) + Math.abs(xLocale);
```

Finally, you could use Java's `Stream` API's [`min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) method with a special Comparator to get the street with the minimum distance to the current location.

```
StreetName temp = streets.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(street -> {
        int yLocale = this.y - street.getY();
        int xLocale = this.x - street.getX();
        return Math.abs(yLocale) + Math.abs(xLocale);
    })).get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @tobias_k